# JavaFX: Add CheckBoxTreeItem in TreeTable?

Tags: java, checkbox, javafx-8, treetableview

I am experimenting with JavaFX and I am trying to add a check box Item in tree table, but it looks like it supports only simple tree item.

My Code is modified version of [Oracle's TreeTableView Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm):

```
 public class TreeTableViewSample extends Application implements Runnable {

List<Employee> employees = Arrays.<Employee>asList(
        new Employee("Ethan Williams", 30.0),
        new Employee("Emma Jones", 10.0),
        new Employee("Michael Brown", 70.0),
        new Employee("Anna Black", 50.0),
        new Employee("Rodger York", 20.0),
        new Employee("Susan Collins", 70.0));

/*  private final ImageView depIcon = new ImageView (
 new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("department.png"))
 );
 */
final CheckBoxTreeItem<Employee> root
        = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(new Employee("Sales Department", 0.0));
final CheckBoxTreeItem<Employee> root2
        = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(new Employee("Departments", 0.0));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(TreeTableViewSample.class, args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    root.setExpanded(true);
    employees.stream().forEach((employee) -> {
        root.getChildren().add(new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(employee));
    });
    stage.setTitle("Tree Table View Sample");
    final Scene scene = new Scene(new Group(), 400, 400);
    scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);
    Group sceneRoot = (Group) scene.getRoot();

    TreeTableColumn<Employee, String> empColumn
            = new TreeTableColumn<>("Employee");
    empColumn.setPrefWidth(150);
    empColumn.setCellValueFactory(
            (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, String> param)
            -> new ReadOnlyStringWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getName())
    );

    TreeTableColumn<Employee, Double> salaryColumn
            = new TreeTableColumn<>("Salary");
    salaryColumn.setPrefWidth(190);
    /*   salaryColumn.setCellValueFactory(
     (TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<Employee, String> param) -> 
     new ReadOnlyDoubleWrapper(param.getValue().getValue().getEmail())
     );
     */
    salaryColumn.setCellFactory(ProgressBarTreeTableCell.<Employee>forTreeTableColumn());
    root2.getChildren().add(root);

    TreeTableView<Employee> treeTableView = new TreeTableView<>(root2);
    treeTableView.getColumns().setAll(empColumn, salaryColumn);
    sceneRoot.getChildren().add(treeTableView);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
    ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(this, 3, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

}

@Override
public void run() {
    root2.getValue().setSalary(calcSalary(root));
}

public double calcSalary(TreeItem<Employee> t) {
    Double salary = 0.0;
    if (!t.isLeaf()) {

        ObservableList<TreeItem<Employee>> al = t.getChildren();
        for (int i = 0; i < al.size(); i++) {
            TreeItem<Employee> get = al.get(i);
            salary += calcSalary(get);
        }
        t.getValue().setSalary(salary);
    }
    return salary += t.getValue().getSalary();
}

public class Employee {

    private SimpleStringProperty name;
    private SimpleDoubleProperty salary;

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        if (name == null) {
            name = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "name");
        }
        return name;
    }

    public SimpleDoubleProperty salaryProperty() {
        if (salary == null) {
            salary = new SimpleDoubleProperty(this, "salary");
        }
        return salary;
    }

    private Employee(String name, Double salary) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.salary = new SimpleDoubleProperty(salary);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public void setName(String fName) {
        name.set(fName);
    }

    public Double getSalary() {
        return salary.get();
    }

    public void setSalary(Double fName) {
        salary.set(fName);
    }
}
}
```

Is there any way i can use checkboxes for tree item in the above example? I am using JavaFx 8.

I am also try to create Salary Bars, which can also be used as progressbar for a task and its sub tasks. (Just playing with UI). But don't know how to connect them with the real values of employe, as i guess normal table view is different from tree table view. Thanks ! :)

Comment: interestingly, it doesn't seem to be supported - you'll need to run your own: probably with a custom CheckBoxTreeTableRow that manages the checkbox similarly as a CheckBoxTreeCell. Unrelated: you could use PropertyValueFactory for your cellValueFactories

Comment: a more adminitrative note: please don't post two unrelated questions in one - it's easier to answer (and check as resolved) if you post them separately.

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks !! And long time no see :). I was just trying to save space on server by putting two question on same page. My apologies if my approach was wrong. :) Can you provide me any example to create my own Custom CheckBoxTreeTableRow as you mentioned in first comment.

Comment: :-) Take a look at the code of CheckBoxTreeCell and take the relevant parts into your custom cell: basically, you need to place the checkbox (might be done in the skin?) and keep it sync to the selectedProperty of the treeItem. Never tried, just from the top of my head

Comment: correction of the "unrelated" part of my first comment: the reflective valueFactory for TreeTableView is TreeItemPropertyValueFactory (note to self: should read java doc more often ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no cell implemenation that corresponds to CheckBoxTreeCell: that is a cell with a checkBox that is bound to the selected/indeterminate property of a CheckBoxTreeItem. The apparent counterpart CheckBoxTreeTableCell is simply a cell with a checkbox, that's bound to the cell data.

What's needed is a CheckBoxTreeTableRow: that's the cell layer that has access to the TreeItem and can manage the bindings between the checkBox and the treeItem. Below is a quick implementation, simplified and adjusted copy of CheckBoxTreeCell. The un/binding is handled in updateItem.

**Update**: Clean solution (lengthy!)

It looks like TableRowSkinBase is prepared to handle custom row graphics, it has an method graphicsProperty() which is used in all layout code inside the row skin.

```
/**
 * Returns the graphic to draw on the inside of the disclosure node. Null
 * is acceptable when no graphic should be shown. Commonly this is the
 * graphic associated with a TreeItem (i.e. treeItem.getGraphic()), rather
 * than a graphic associated with a cell.
 */
protected abstract ObjectProperty<Node> graphicProperty();
```

TreeTableRowSkin implements it to return the graphic of the TreeItem, so overriding to return the graphic of the tableRow should be working. Except ... it isn't - layout is crooked as noted in the original hacky answer below. Digging exposed the culprit: it's TreeTableCellSkin which hard-codes it own layout code to account for any graphics in its padding to ... the treeItem's graphic.

So a complete solution needs

- a Tree/TableCellSkin that doesn't hard-code the treeItem graphics (the example below is still not entirely clean, it relies on super having added the graphics width and substracts it again)
- a Tree/TableCell that installs the enhanced skin
- a Tree/TableRowSkin that overrides graphicsProperty as needed, below returning the row graphic
- a Tree/TableRow that updates its graphics as needed, below setting its graphic to a checkBox which in turn might contain the treeItem's graphic

The first couple is named DefaultTreeTableCell/Skin, the second CheckBoxTreeTableRow/Skin below.

Usage (snippets to insert into OPs example)

```
// just for fun, have root items with some graphic
final CheckBoxTreeItem<Employee> root = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(
        new Employee("Sales Department", 0.0), new Circle(10, Color.RED));
final CheckBoxTreeItem<Employee> root2 = new CheckBoxTreeItem<>(
        new Employee("Departments", 0.0), new Circle(10, Color.BLUE));

// configure treeTableView to use the extended tableRow 
treeTableView.setRowFactory(item -> new CheckBoxTreeTableRow<>());

// configure table columns to use the extended table cell
empColumn.setCellFactory(p -> new DefaultTreeTableCell<>());
// all cell types must have a skin that copes with row graphics
salaryColumn.setCellFactory(e -> {
    TreeTableCell cell = new ProgressBarTreeTableCell() {

        @Override
        protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
            return new DefaultTreeTableCell.DefaultTreeTableCellSkin<>(this);
        }

    };
    return cell;
});
```

Cell/Row implementaions:

```
/**
 * TreeTableCell actually showing something. This is copied from TreeTableColumn plus
 * installs DefaultTreeTableCellSkin which handles row graphic width.
 */
public class DefaultTreeTableCell<S, T> extends TreeTableCell<S, T> {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        if (item == getItem()) return;

        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (item == null) {
            super.setText(null);
            super.setGraphic(null);
        } else if (item instanceof Node) {
            super.setText(null);
            super.setGraphic((Node)item);
        } else {
            super.setText(item.toString());
            super.setGraphic(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new DefaultTreeTableCellSkin<>(this);
    }

    /**
     * TreeTableCellSkin that handles row graphic in its leftPadding, if
     * it is in the treeColumn of the associated TreeTableView.
     * <p>
     * It assumes that per-row graphics - including the graphic of the TreeItem, if any -
     * is folded into the TreeTableRow graphic and patches its leftLabelPadding
     * to account for the graphic width.
     * <p>
     * 
     * Note: TableRowSkinBase seems to be designed to cope with variations of row 
     * graphic - it has a method <code>graphicProperty()</code> that's always used
     * internally when calculating offsets in the treeColumn.
     * Subclasses override as needed, the layout code remains constant. The real 
     * problem is the TreeTableCell hard-codes the TreeItem as the only graphic
     * owner. 
     *  
     */
    public static class DefaultTreeTableCellSkin<S, T> extends TreeTableCellSkin<S, T> {

        /**
         * @param treeTableCell
         */
        public DefaultTreeTableCellSkin(TreeTableCell<S, T> treeTableCell) {
            super(treeTableCell);
        }

        /**
         * Overridden to adjust the padding returned by super for row graphic.
         */
        @Override
        protected double leftLabelPadding() {
            double padding = super.leftLabelPadding();
            padding += getRowGraphicPatch();
            return padding;
        }

        /**
         * Returns the patch for leftPadding if the tableRow has a graphic of
         * its own.<p>
         * 
         * Note: this implemenation is a bit whacky as it relies on super's 
         * handling of treeItems graphics offset. A cleaner 
         * implementation would override leftLabelPadding from scratch.
         * <p>
         * PENDING JW: doooooo it!
         * 
         * @return
         */
        protected double getRowGraphicPatch() {
            if (!isTreeColumn()) return 0;
            Node graphic = getSkinnable().getTreeTableRow().getGraphic();
            if (graphic != null) {
                double height = getCellSize();
                // start with row's graphic
                double patch = graphic.prefWidth(height);
                // correct for super's having added treeItem's graphic
                TreeItem<S> item = getSkinnable().getTreeTableRow().getTreeItem();
                if (item.getGraphic() != null) {
                    double correct = item.getGraphic().prefWidth(height);
                    patch -= correct;
                }
                return patch;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        /**
         * Checks and returns whether our cell is attached to a treeTableView/column
         * and actually has a TreeItem.
         * @return
         */
        protected boolean isTreeColumn() {
            if (getSkinnable().isEmpty()) return false;
            TreeTableColumn<S, T> column = getSkinnable().getTableColumn();
            TreeTableView<S> view = getSkinnable().getTreeTableView();
            if (column.equals(view.getTreeColumn())) return true;
            return view.getVisibleLeafColumns().indexOf(column) == 0;
        }

    }

}

/**
 * Support custom graphic for Tree/TableRow. Here in particular a checkBox.
 * http://stackoverflow.com/q/29300551/203657
 * <p>
 * Basic idea: implement custom TreeTableRow that set's its graphic to the 
 * graphic/checkBox. Doesn't work: layout is broken, graphic appears
 * over the text. All fine if we set the graphic to the TreeItem that's
 * shown. Possible as long as the treeItem doesn't have a graphic of
 * its own.
 * <p>
 * Basic problem:
 * <li> TableRowSkinBase seems to be able to cope: has protected method
 *   graphicsProperty that should be implemented to return the graphic 
 *   if any. That graphic is added to the children list and sized/located
 *   in layoutChildren. 
 * <li> are added the graphic/disclosureNode as needed before
 *   calling super.layoutChildren,  
 * <li> graphic/disclosure are placed inside the leftPadding of the tableCell
 *   that is the treeColumn
 * <li> TreeTableCellSkin must cooperate in taking into account the graphic/disclosure 
 *   when calculating its leftPadding
 * <li> cellSkin is hard-coded to use the TreeItem's graphic (vs. the rowCell's)   
 *
 * PENDING JW: 
 * <li>- would expect to not alter the scenegraph during layout (might lead to
 *   endless loops or not) but done frequently in core code   
 * <p> 
 *  
 * Outline of the solution as implemented:
 * <li> need a TreeTableCell with a custom skin
 * <li> override leftPadding in skin to add row graphic if available
 * <li> need CheckBoxTreeTableRow that sets its graphic to checkBox (or a combination
 *   of checkBox and treeItem's)
 * <li> need custom rowSkin that implements graphicProperty to return the row graphic  
 *    
 * @author Jeanette Winzenburg, Berlin
 * 
 * @see DefaultTreeTableCell
 * @see DefaultTreeTableCellSkin
 * 
 */
public class CheckBoxTreeTableRow<T> extends TreeTableRow<T> {

    private CheckBox checkBox;

    private ObservableValue<Boolean> booleanProperty;

    private BooleanProperty indeterminateProperty;

    public CheckBoxTreeTableRow() {
        this(item -> {
            if (item instanceof CheckBoxTreeItem<?>) {
                return ((CheckBoxTreeItem<?>)item).selectedProperty();
            }
            return null;
        });
    }

    public CheckBoxTreeTableRow(
            final Callback<TreeItem<T>, ObservableValue<Boolean>> getSelectedProperty) {
        this.getStyleClass().add("check-box-tree-cell");
        setSelectedStateCallback(getSelectedProperty);
        checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    }

    // --- selected state callback property
    private ObjectProperty<Callback<TreeItem<T>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>> 
            selectedStateCallback = 
            new SimpleObjectProperty<Callback<TreeItem<T>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>>(
            this, "selectedStateCallback");

    /**
     * Property representing the {@link Callback} that is bound to by the 
     * CheckBox shown on screen.
     */
    public final ObjectProperty<Callback<TreeItem<T>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>> selectedStateCallbackProperty() { 
        return selectedStateCallback; 
    }

    /** 
     * Sets the {@link Callback} that is bound to by the CheckBox shown on screen.
     */
    public final void setSelectedStateCallback(Callback<TreeItem<T>, ObservableValue<Boolean>> value) { 
        selectedStateCallbackProperty().set(value); 
    }

    /**
     * Returns the {@link Callback} that is bound to by the CheckBox shown on screen.
     */
    public final Callback<TreeItem<T>, ObservableValue<Boolean>> getSelectedStateCallback() { 
        return selectedStateCallbackProperty().get(); 
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override 
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            TreeItem<T> treeItem = getTreeItem();
            checkBox.setGraphic(treeItem == null ? null : treeItem.getGraphic());
            setGraphic(checkBox);
            // uninstall bindings
            if (booleanProperty != null) {
                checkBox.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional((BooleanProperty)booleanProperty);
            }
            if (indeterminateProperty != null) {
                checkBox.indeterminateProperty().unbindBidirectional(indeterminateProperty);
            }

            // install new bindings.
            // this can only handle TreeItems of type CheckBoxTreeItem
            if (treeItem instanceof CheckBoxTreeItem) {
                CheckBoxTreeItem<T> cbti = (CheckBoxTreeItem<T>) treeItem;
                booleanProperty = cbti.selectedProperty();
                checkBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional((BooleanProperty)booleanProperty);

                indeterminateProperty = cbti.indeterminateProperty();
                checkBox.indeterminateProperty().bindBidirectional(indeterminateProperty);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("item must be CheckBoxTreeItem");
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected Skin<?> createDefaultSkin() {
        return new CheckBoxTreeTableRowSkin<>(this);
    }

    public static class CheckBoxTreeTableRowSkin<S> extends TreeTableRowSkin<S> {
        protected ObjectProperty<Node> checkGraphic;

        /**
         * @param control
         */
        public CheckBoxTreeTableRowSkin(TreeTableRow<S> control) {
            super(control);
        }

        /**
         * Note: this is implicitly called from the constructor of LabeledSkinBase.
         * At that time, checkGraphic is not yet instantiated. So we do it here,
         * still having to create it at least twice. That'll be a problem if 
         * anybody would listen to changes ...
         */
        @Override
        protected ObjectProperty<Node> graphicProperty() {
            if (checkGraphic == null) {
                checkGraphic = new SimpleObjectProperty<Node>(this, "checkGraphic");
            }
            CheckBoxTreeTableRow<S> treeTableRow = getTableRow();
            if (treeTableRow.getTreeItem() == null) {
                checkGraphic.set(null);   
            } else {
                checkGraphic.set(treeTableRow.getGraphic());
            }
            return checkGraphic;
        }

        protected CheckBoxTreeTableRow<S> getTableRow() {
            return (CheckBoxTreeTableRow<S>) super.getSkinnable();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger
            .getLogger(CheckBoxTreeTableRow.class.getName());
}
```

---

Original answer: hack!

There's a nutty line of code in it:

```
treeItem.setGraphics(checkBox);
```

That's really whacky, and probably will cause havoc eventually - it's a hack around a layout glitch in TreeTableRowSkin, that for some reason (I couldn't dig up) cannot position a graphic set to the cell. Couldn't make it behave in a custom CheckBoxTreeTableRowSkin that returns the checkBox directly in its `graphicProperty()` - so here we go with the hack for now.

```
/**
 * @author Jeanette Winzenburg, Berlin
 */
public class CheckBoxTreeTableRowHack<T> extends TreeTableRow<T> {

    private CheckBox checkBox;

    private ObservableValue<Boolean> booleanProperty;

    private BooleanProperty indeterminateProperty;

    public CheckBoxTreeTableRowHack() {
        setSelectedStateCallback(item -> {
            if (item instanceof CheckBoxTreeItem<?>) {
                return ((CheckBoxTreeItem<?>)item).selectedProperty();
            }
            return null;
        });
        this.checkBox = new CheckBox();
        // something weird going on with layout
        checkBox.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
    }

    // --- selected state callback property
    private ObjectProperty<Callback<TreeItem<T>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>> 
            selectedStateCallback = 
            new SimpleObjectProperty<Callback<TreeItem<T>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>>(
            this, "selectedStateCallback");

    /**
     * Property representing the {@link Callback} that is bound to by the 
     * CheckBox shown on screen.
     */
    public final ObjectProperty<Callback<TreeItem<T>, ObservableValue<Boolean>>> selectedStateCallbackProperty() { 
        return selectedStateCallback; 
    }

    /** 
     * Sets the {@link Callback} that is bound to by the CheckBox shown on screen.
     */
    public final void setSelectedStateCallback(Callback<TreeItem<T>, ObservableValue<Boolean>> value) { 
        selectedStateCallbackProperty().set(value); 
    }

    /**
     * Returns the {@link Callback} that is bound to by the CheckBox shown on screen.
     */
    public final Callback<TreeItem<T>, ObservableValue<Boolean>> getSelectedStateCallback() { 
        return selectedStateCallbackProperty().get(); 
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override 
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
//            
            TreeItem<T> treeItem = getTreeItem();
            // PENDING JW: this is nuts but working ..  certainly will pose problems
            // when re-using the cell
            treeItem.setGraphic(checkBox);
            // this is what CheckBoxTreeCell does, setting the graphic
            // of the tableRow confuses the layout
//            checkBox.setGraphic(treeItem == null ? null : treeItem.getGraphic());
//            setGraphic(checkBox);

            // uninstall bindings
            if (booleanProperty != null) {
                checkBox.selectedProperty().unbindBidirectional((BooleanProperty)booleanProperty);
            }
            if (indeterminateProperty != null) {
                checkBox.indeterminateProperty().unbindBidirectional(indeterminateProperty);
            }

            // install new bindings.
            // We special case things when the TreeItem is a CheckBoxTreeItem
            if (treeItem instanceof CheckBoxTreeItem) {
                CheckBoxTreeItem<T> cbti = (CheckBoxTreeItem<T>) treeItem;
                booleanProperty = cbti.selectedProperty();
                checkBox.selectedProperty().bindBidirectional((BooleanProperty)booleanProperty);

                indeterminateProperty = cbti.indeterminateProperty();
                checkBox.indeterminateProperty().bindBidirectional(indeterminateProperty);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalStateException("item must be CheckBoxTreeItem");
            }
        }

    }
}

// usage: in the example add
treeTableView.setRowFactory(f -> new CheckBoxTreeTableRowHack<>());
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. Do i need to replace `CheckBoxTreeItem<Employee>` with `CheckBoxTreeTableRowHack<Employee>` after creating `CheckBoxTreeTableRowHack` class. Or is there other way to implement this?

Comment: @DeepSidhu1313 no, the item is just the same as  in your example (in fact it's required) - you need to install a rowFactory that creates the custom TreeTableRow. Will update the answer.

Comment: I almost forgot, how to set ProgressBar Value in my example?

Comment: @DeepSidhu1313 as already mentioned, that's a different question :-)

Comment: LOL :P, SO here is the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365814/javafx-add-progressbar-in-treetableview